# ASA 5505 routing issues

Tags: cisco, routing, cisco-asa

I have recently configured a Dell PowerConnect 5524 with 3 VLANs ([Dell PowerConnect 5524 VLAN routing](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4929/dell-powerconnect-5524-vlan-routing)).

I have connected this switch to our network with an IP of 192.168.2.254, it successfully routes traffic from the 192.168.3.0/24 subnet and even gets ping replies from our main router (the ASA on 192.168.2.1 and my PC 192.168.2.41) however if I try from my PC to ping anything on the other subnet, including the Dell's .3 IP (192.168.3.2), I get nothing.

I have added this route on the ASA:

```
route inside 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.254
```

This doesn't seem to work.

If I add the route on my PC itself (via `route add` in the command prompt) everything works fine.

The ASA and the Dell are directly connected via cable from port 21 on the Dell (VLAN 2, Internal .2) to port 5 on the ASA (VLAN 1, INSIDE).

If I change the default gateway in Windows on my PC to the IP address of the Dell on this subnet (192.168.2.254), I can access devices on the other subnet with no problems.

Full config for the PowerConnect can be found [here](http://www.saairey.co.uk/PowerConnect-5524-running-config.txt).

Full config for the ASA (IPs and sensitive info has been blanked out) can be found [here](http://www.saairey.co.uk/ASA-5505-running-config.txt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the switch as the default gateway for all of your subnets. For your scenario the default gateway of hosts on Vlan 3 should be set to 192.168.3.2 and hosts on Vlan 2 should be set to 192.168.2.254.

Comment: The routing on the Dell works fine (and I have entered the `ip routing` command on the Dell many times, as I mentioned in my other question), I had it under my desk before I took it up to the server room and when I had PCs plugged into ports on different VLANs the routing was working. Also, I can change my default gateway in Windows to the IP address of the Dell and have my traffic routed through to the 192.168.3.0 subnet no problems at all now that it is upstairs.

Comment: Actually we have our SBS server configured as the gateway for our PCs, don't ask why because I don't know =] if I change my PCs default gateway to the IP of the ASA (192.168.2.1) I still have the same problem.

Comment: The point of the Dell is to bridge the two subnets. Everything goes through the ASA at the moment and I should be able to have the ASA point packets destined for the .3 subnet to the Dell. I wouldn't have the gateways and switching set up the way it is now if I had it my way but this is what I have got to work with. I need the ASA to be able to route packets into the .3 subnet via the Dell, which it is more than capable of doing.

Answer (score 2):

If you're dead set on using the ASA to route local traffic instead of the switch, you will need to update the ASA with NAT statements for inter-VLAN communication and also add `same-security-traffic permit intra-interface` to the configuration to allow traffic to go to the ASA and back out the ASA on the same interface.